# Global variance of a variable which has a varying variance

Tags: statistics, variance, noise

I am trying to know what is the global variance of a noisy signal. If noise characteristics were constant, its power would represent the variance of my signal. But noise power is varying, so the variance it will create on the signal. The noise power has a mean and a variance.
Some idea to handle this problem ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to know the total variance of my signal that is noisy. But power of this noise (variance it will add to my signal) is not constant. This power has a statistical distribution, let's say gaussian, with a mean and a variance.

Comment: It is like determining sigma of N(mean,N(mean,sigma)). N is normal distribution.